# PHP-MySQLi Prepared Statement not working in code but working is PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running a prepared statement and I get the following error. I cant understand what the problem is. As the same query is working fine in PHPMyAdmin.

#### Code

```
$queryConstruct = "
    SELECT id FROM registrations WHERE 
        email = '$email' 
    AND 
        license_type = $license_type";
```

#### Error

**Fatal error**: Problem preparing query ( **SELECT id FROM registrations WHERE email = 'test1@gmail.com' AND license_type = 0**) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **''test1@gmail.com' AND license_type = 0' ** at line 2 in mysqli.lib.php on line 444

Comment: This isn't a prepared statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A prepared statement would look like this

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `registgrations` 
WHERE `email` = :email
AND `license_type` = :license_type
```

Checkout the PDO manual docs to learn how to use it.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a prepared statement, exactly - as been said by Rottingham.
From [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM Registrations WHERE email=? AND license_type=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $license_type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    printf("%s - %s - %s\n", $id, $email, $license_tpe)
    $stmt->close();
}
```

No sure if i edited correctly, though. In any case, this should hint you that what you did wasn't a prepared statement.

Notice that instead of concatenating the actual values in your queries, they are replaced with **placeholders** ('?' in this case), then bound by values. This way, [SQL Injection](http://www.sqlinjection.net/) can be prevented from manipulating your query, thereby ruining your data.

More so, consider studying about the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) class for a much easier approach.